# React Ant modal props of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd, react-props

I'm using [ant design modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/). when I click ok at confirmation dialog box. I'm getting error like `props of undefined` where as when I use outside of confirm it works fine.

**Code:**

```
confirm({
    title: 'Do you Want to delete these items?',
    content: 'Some descriptions',
    onOk() {
      this.props.actions.delete()
    },
    onCancel() {
      console.log('Cancel');
    },
  });
```

**Error**:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/k94004l1wv

Comment: Where do you have actions defined? i.e, this.props.actions.delete?

Comment: it's better to keep index.js clean (use only render function) for rest of the stuff create another component and render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this.props.actions.delete in codeSandbox. But I want to correct the way you are doing things

Take a look at this [corrected sandboc](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjkmjxro7q) of yours for better understanding about doing things in react

Comment: @Selvin kindly do accept and upvote if the answer resolved the issue. So that it will help future readers

Comment: The sandbox does not demonstrate `this` being bound to the class inside the `confirm` function. I'm running into the same issue. I tried binding it inside the constructor: `this.boundConfirm = confirm.bind(this)`, but `this` is still `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it can be solved by making it arrow function like this:**

```
confirm({
          title: `Are you sure to log out?`,
          okText: 'Yes',
          cancelText: 'No',
          onOk : () => {
            return this.handleLogOut();
          },
          onCancel() {
            console.log('Cancel');
          },
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Although another answer was marked accepted, I feel it does not address the real issue. The problem is that the `onOk` (and the `onCancel`) function are not bound. The value of `this` will be `undefined`. Resolve this by explicitly binding the class reference: `.bind(this)`, or by replacing `onOk` by an arrow function, which will take `this` from the outer scope.

See also: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5269#issuecomment-347836625